# Is there a way to edit a built-in command in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I like using the Toggle Block Comment command (`editor.action.blockComment`) with its default keybinding, but I don't like the fact that it only makes block comments that look like this

```
/*
I don't like this
*/
```

I want something more like this

```
/**
* Oh yeah...
**/
```

Is there a way to edit what the Toggle Block Comment command (`editor.action.blockComment`) does?

Comment: insert snippet on a key binding, use the selected text, split it in lines using regex with `g` flag and add a `*` in front of each line. Or write a small extension that does the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own custom extension to achieve this. Here is the code:

```
    let selectedText = activeEditor.document.getText(activeEditor.selection);
    selectedText = selectedText.replace(/^/gm, "* ");
    selectedText = '/** \n' + selectedText + '\n**/';

    activeEditor.edit((edittedText) => {
        edittedText.replace(activeEditor.selection, selectedText);
    })
```

I am also working on an extension where you will find exactly this. I will update the name once it hits the marketplace.